# oracle sequence init

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I wanted to export 3 tables from db1 into db2.

Before the export starts, I will create the sequences for those 3 tables.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

After the export, I will reinitialize sequnce values to match the max(id) + 1 from the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST_SEQUENCE"
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
is
v_num number;
begin
select max(ID)  into v_num from TABLE_1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ  INCREMENT BY ' || v_num;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE 1TEST_SEQ  INCREMENT BY 1'; 
end;
/
show errors;
execute TEST_SEQ;
```

This procedure compiles and executes without problems.

But when I want to check t he last value of the sequence, like 
select TEST_SEQ.nextval from dual;

I still get the "1".

Can someone tell me why my procedure did not impact my sequence?
ps. I am using oracle sql developper to pass sql.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually make the sequence increment between the two `alter` statements:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ  INCREMENT BY ' || v_num;
select test_seq.nextval into v_num from dual;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ  INCREMENT BY 1';
```

In 11g you can assign the sequence directly:

```
v_num := test_seq.nextval;
```

Either way you don't need to do anything with that value, you just need to generate it.

Alternatively you could create the sequences after the load, and set the starting value based on what you just loaded.

Comment: thanks, i forgot to increment my sequence! your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ  INCREMENT BY 1000;
```

does not change actual value of sequence. You have to select TEST_SEQ.nextval and you will increment actual value by 1000.

You have several posibileties how to solve your problem.

1) DROP sequence and CREATE in again

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH xxxx;
```

where xxxx is your new number. By dropping sequence you lose privileges granted on it, you have to grant them again.

2) use you way, but slightly modified

```
ALTER SEQUENCE test_seq INCREMENT BY yyy;
SELECT test_seq.nextval FROM dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE test_seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

where yyy is difference between actual sequence number and new value

3) Shift sequence number in PLSQL loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are starting at 1, if you run your select again you will find it has incremented as you expected. You need to set the start value of your sequence too.

try something like:

```
create sequence xxx start with 100 increment by 10;
```

or more specifically:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ  start with ' || v_num || 'INCREMENT BY ' || v_num;
```